# Can I assign a value to a $_POST variable in PHP?

Tags: php, post

For example, I am using a $_POST variable to insert data into a DB. Just before this query I have a few tests and if they are true I want to adjust that (hidden) $_POST value.

**Ex.**

```
if($baby_dragon_eats_children){
  $_POST['hidden_value'] = "grapes";
}
```

Can $_POST['hidden_value'] be assigned a new value and then be passed to another function as $_POST and be able to access the new $_POST['hidden_value']?

Thanks

---

**$_POST['consolidate_answers']**

- **IF** you assign a value to $_POST you should document is very clearly as it is not common nor considered "best" practice.
- **IF** you have any extensions of PHP such as [Suhosin Patch](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/)... it may block such actions..
- **Handle** your own arrays, don't depend on $_POST!
- **IF** need be, make a copy of $_POST and work with that.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can assign values to `$_POST`, but if you do so you should document it very clearly with comments both at the point of assignment and the later point of access.   Manually manipulating `$_POST` can break future programmers' (including your own) expectations of what is in the superglobal and where it came from.

There may be other alternatives, like:

```
$my_post = $_POST;
$my_post['hidden_value'] = 12345;

// In a function:
function func() {
   // Emulate a superglobal
   echo $GLOBALS['mypost']['hidden_value'];
}
```

Comment: I just feel that if I use a separate variable for these values it is pointless to have my hidden input in the first place? Is this considered bad practice? I probably should remove hidden value and just assign a variable the results of these tests and use that.

Comment: @KRB with the method above, you aren't using a separate value -- you're replacing `$_POST` with `$my_post` for future use.  I would consider it bad practice to manipulate `$_POST`, though I admit to having done it myself from time to time.  As long as you comment your intentions very clearly, it is probably ok.

Comment: Commenting your intentions won't really help other places in the code that need the $_POST variable, that may or may not be written by him (or he himself may some day not remember his dreadful global manipulations).

Comment: @Yam the implication is that it is commented both at assignment and access. Sorry that's not clear in my post

Comment: I can see that, but $_POST, being a global variable, might be accessed from anywhere in the program, and the programmer who wants to use it doesn't have to know of the existence of any certain piece of code which accesses or assigns it.

Answer (score 11):

> Can $_POST['hidden_value'] be assigned a new value and then be passed to another function as $_POST and be able to access the new $_POST['hidden_value']?

It can in normal PHP.

However, extensions like the [Suhosin Patch](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/) may block this.

Also, it feels wrong in general. `$_POST` is intended to contain the raw, incoming POST data - nothing else. It should not be modified IMO.

A better way to go would be to fetch all the data you plan to insert into the database into an array, and do the manipulations in that array instead.

Answer (score 5):

You can, it will work, but don't.

Create a copy of `$_POST`, perform your tests on that and modify that instead. For example.

```
$postdata = $_POST;
if ($postdata['somevalue'] != 'someothervalue') $postdata['newvalue'] = 'anothervalue';
// ...
```

If you manipulate variables auto-created by PHP, it will probably come back to haunt you later on when the variable doesn't hold the data you expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

Find an alternative!

The $_POST variable has a distinct responsibility. Do not abuse its globalism.

I'd say don't abuse globalism either way, even if it means changing the design you have (or have in mind).

But if you choose not to, then consider creating a dedicated global registry just for your needs.
Don't manipulate language built-ins.

Comment: My Professor would always say, "Global Variables Stink!". Sounds good man, thanks for the advice!!